# Rich's ants colony demo principles applicable to 'powder toy' type game?

Tags: clojure

I'm toying in my free time with a sandbox/world simulation/powdertoy type of game using clojure and quil. The idea here is that each coordinate/unit in the world can have one identity (sand/water/air/plant) with certain properties (light/heath etc). In each iteration each coordinate gets updated only taking in account the coordinate next to it (recieves heat from a warmer coordinate/ water falls down when there is air underneat it)

Updating the world can get offcourse very computing intensive the bigger the world gets. But speed is not my highest priority (say for example 5-10 iterations/ second is good enough).

I was wondering if it would be feasible to update each unit in the world in parralel using the concurrency principles used in Rich's [ants colony](https://gist.github.com/spacemanaki/1093917) demo where each ant has its own thread. (so each unit in the world get its own thread). I have a really hard time to wrap my head arround all the things that are happening in the ant colony demo. Would there be a problem when for example 2 sand units try to move to the same air unit at the same time? Can there exist that many threads? (eg 500 000 coordinates -> 500 000 threads). Or would it be best forget about all of this and just update all coordinates sequently.I was also thinking about introducing kind of static flag for each coordinate. So I only have to update the coordinates where there could be a change. (using a vector of changable coordinates in the next iteration)

Greetings and thanks for reading. :)

Comment: I doubt each ant gets its own thread in Rich's program - what makes you think that?

Comment: I am new to these things so it can be that I'm wrong. I thought that this was the point of this concurency demo, to compute the changes of the ants in parralel in parralel runing threads. But again, it can be that I'm very wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [Clojure Ants - a Literate Programming Version](https://github.com/limist/literate-clojure-ants), which explains Rich's code really well.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually allready read this. I still couldn't figure out wat exactly happens if (in my case) 2 units interacts with the same unit/data. (eg. 2 sands move to the same air space at the same time in 2 different threads)

Comment: The mechanics of your game is not really clear to me, but it sounds closer to the Game of Life than ants.clj. 500K threads is certainly not feasible.

Comment: In game of life dies or live a position each iteration but not move from one position to another. So here you can not have the problem of 1 sands going to the same air postion or am I seeing this wrong?